# Doesn't Start WIFI protable hotspot in Marshmallow

Tags: android

Here is my code switchbutton code.

```
switchWifi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                turnOnOffWifi(BuddeeCityInsiderActivity.this, false);
                setWifiTetheringEnabled(false);
                if (isChecked) {
                    turnOnOffHotspot(BuddeeCityInsiderActivity.this, true);
                } else {
                    turnOnOffHotspot(BuddeeCityInsiderActivity.this, false);
                }
            }
        });
```

But I'm going to take permission in onCreate()

like:

```
    private void getPermission() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                BuddeeCityInsiderActivity.this,
                getString(R.string.contact),
                HOTSPOT_PHONE,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
                );

    } else {

    }

}
```

on Clicking switchButton call this method with respective param:

```
 private void setWifiTetheringEnabled(boolean enable) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    Method[] methods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) {
            try {
                method.invoke(wifiManager, null, enable);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**In Android L working fine but problem in Android M or M+ Please give me some solution**